# Extract contents of files from remote ftp server without writing to file in local disk

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, apache-tika

After establishing connection to a remote `ftp` or `sftp` server programmatically using java is it possible to read the files of `/home/www-data/content/` without writing to a file in local system. Basically i want to extract metadata of files using [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) from that path without downloading.

**UPDATE :**

I have tried to connect with [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which is an implementation of `SSH2`.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);
session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
```

Comment: It definitely is possible but you will have to provide more details on how you connect to remote ftp/sftp from your Java code - what library you use etc

Comment: @rootkit007 : I have updated my question with what i have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

For SFTP using JSCH library you should use ChannelSFTP.get() method and supply OutputStream instance that does not write to disk (eg, ByteArrayOutputStream). See JSCH stock example here:

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html

And JavaDoc for get() method:

http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#get(java.lang.String,java.io.OutputStream,com.jcraft.jsch.SftpProgressMonitor,int,long)

For FTP you will have to use something else as JSCH only supports SFTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try out [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/index.html) (Virtual File System).

They have a pretty decent [example of a simple SFTP file download](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/SimpleSftpFileDownload), but in your case you could just change the `process()` method of that example and let it parse the file with TIKA.

With commons vfs you can just work with a `FileObject` . On the FileObject you can call doGetInputStream() which in turn you can hand over to TIKA for further processing.